Ortho Size Changes When I Change The Window Size
I wrote two functions that adjust the position of the game window, but each time these functions run, the size of the game objects either increases or decreases. It’s probably a resolution-related issue.
Code:
public void IncreaseWindowHeightByOne()
    {
        int handle = GetActiveWindow();
        RECT windowRect;
        if (GetWindowRect(handle, out windowRect))
        {
            int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
            int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
            height += 1;

            SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE);
        }
    }

    public void DecreaseWindowHeightByOne()
    {
        int handle = GetActiveWindow();
        RECT windowRect;
        if (GetWindowRect(handle, out windowRect))
        {
            int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
            int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
            height -= 1;

            SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE);
        }
    }

I want the size of the game objects to remain the same. How can I solve this problem?
